# Change Symfony voting strategy dynamically

Tags: symfony, security, acl, symfony-security

With the Symfony `Voters` system it's pretty easy to get a good ACL up and running for a web app. However, you have to decide in the beginning, what strategy you'd like to use.

Symfony supports 3 strategies: `affirmative`, `consensus` and `unanimous` (see their [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html#changing-the-access-decision-strategy))

> `affirmative` (default): This grants access as soon as there is one voter granting access;
>   `consensus`: This grants access if there are more voters granting access than denying;
>   `unanimous`: This only grants access once all voters grant access.

I'm currently using the `affirmative` strategy. In one special case (so far, maybe there'll be more in the future), I need to use the `unanimous` strategy.

Is there a way to do this or do I just have to make a custom checking system there (copy the code of all involved voters)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried extending Symfony's `AccessDecisionManager` by your custom class with own strategy and registering it at service container? You can checkout the implementation of this class and see that you can define your own strategy by creating a simple method inside the class.

The other option is you can try to use `access_control` and `allow_if` as said [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html)

Comment: Would this mean to have an own `AccessDecisionManager` with an own strategy, which then would be registered as main manager and in there to have something like "if it's voter `foobar`, then check all the following, otherwise just check until the first that's matching or the end?

Comment: Yep, something like this. Any logic inside your custom strategy.